# Ionic sidemenu disable links

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I am making my first project with ionic.

I have a side menu on the left side where I list all the sites.
The sites are steps. Like, step1, step2, step3 and so on.
My plan is to display all the steps in the sidemenu so the user can always go back to older steps, but he shouldn't be able to click new steps before completing the actual step.

so all I need is to make the links in my sidemenu not clickable. how to do this in ionic?

in app.component.ts i can say which sites i want:

```
  constructor(public platform: Platform, public statusBar: StatusBar, public splashScreen: SplashScreen) {
this.initializeApp();

// used for an example of ngFor and navigation
this.pages = [
{ title: 'Step 1', component: Step1Page },
{ title: 'Step 2', component: Step2Page },
{ title: 'Step 3', component: Step3Page },
```

but where can i tell to display them not clickable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a property of `disabled` to your pages object and in your list you disable a button if the disable is true, like this:

app.components:

```
pages: Array<{ title: string, component: any, disabled: boolean }>; //MODIFY YOUR PAGES ARRAY DECLARATION SO IT ACCEPTS A DISABLE PROPERTY
constructor(public platform: Platform, public statusBar: StatusBar, public splashScreen: SplashScreen) {
  this.initializeApp();

  // used for an example of ngFor and navigation
  this.pages = [
    { title: 'Step 1', component: Step1Page, disabled: false },
    { title: 'Step 2', component: Step2Page, disabled: true },
    { title: 'Step 3', component: Step3Page, disabled: true },
  ];
};
```

app.html:

```
<ion-list>
  <button menuClose ion-item *ngFor="let p of pages" (click)="openPage(p)" [disabled]="p.disabled">
    {{p.title}}
  </button>
</ion-list>
```

See that i've added a binded property `[disabled]` that'll receive the page.disabled property and will disable the button if it's true.

Snce it's in the app.components the menu'll not update as the user complete the steps, i sugest you using [Events](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/util/Events/) to controll it.

Hope this helps

### EDIT

Since you can send data through the events what you can do is send a number to identify the position of this button on the `pages` array, so in your `app.components` you'll have a event like this:

```
constructor(public events: Events){
  events.subscribe('steps', step => {
    this.events[step].disabled = false;
    // The 'step' on the callback will be the number of the step.
  });
}
```

And in your button, for every page and every step you can publish a event for only one event, but passing the number of the next page you'll enable in your `pages` array.

```
public myButtonFunction = () => {
  this.events.publish('step', 1).then(() => { //YOUR CODE });
}
```

Comment: Thx for ur answer. It is helping a lot. I declared the events in app.components and also in every step. The plan was, to activate a button after clicking on next. So in every "next" button, i have a "this.events.publish('Step 1', false);" But how to i bind this in app.components so it can display the menu right?

Comment: @hatemjapo i edited my answer explaining how to use the events for your purpouse. If it helps don't forget to accept my answer. Changing a menu button from disabled true to false will make the button appear as clickable.